# counting data points using loops

Tags: python, loops

Download the stock data at: https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/sandp500 for the last 5 years.

Let's call one day's data -

```
date, open, high, low, close # one data point.
```

Write a loop that counts the number of data points for a single symbol (we'll call each stock a symbol).

Now write an outer loop that calls this for *N* symbols.

Draw a graph that captures the run time vs symbol count (value of *N*) for this pair of loops.

For
*N = 1, N = 10, N=100-500 in stops of 100.*

Measure the actual run time, not the elapsed wall
clocktime.

Comment: Question seems like a homework to me. And we cannot see what have you done so far care to elaborate ?

Comment: Kindly refer to the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question on SO. Kindly show some efforts from your side too.

Comment: i started this problem importing python pandas and numpy and reading the stock dataset as a dataframe i am new to python or any coding so having difficulty in writing the loops and iterating the entire dataset throuigh it